# What is the best way to pass parameter to IN operator SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, in-operator

In my web application which returns a comma-separated string and I need to pass that string to the stored procedure, to retrieve the data from the database. To achieve that, I simply wrote the following stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllUserBySupervisor]
(
    @values varchar(8000) 
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @sql nvarchar(200)

    set @sql = 'SELECT * from [user] WHERE  FkSpID in (' + @values + ')'
    execute sp_executesql @sql   

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
        DECLARE @ErrMsg       VARCHAR(4000),
                @ErrSeverity  INT

        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
               @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1);
    END CATCH
END
```

This is how I execute the procedure:

```
EXEC [spGetAllUserBySupervisor]
        @values = N'10004,10025'

EXEC [spGetAllUserBySupervisor]
        @values = N'10004,10025,10050'
```

This procedure works fine but, When considering the security this is not the best way to this. Because I think someone can SQL inject a dangerous clause. So what is the most appropriate solution to do this?

Comment: You can take a look at `Table-Valued Parameter` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sachith give me a try. if you encounter problem, post a new question

Answer (score 0):

what version of SQL are you using? from 2016 you can use STRING_SPLIT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Or you could write your own function to split the string into a table. This method would remove the dynamic SQL I think you're wanting to get rid of.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete answer to my question, how can I do it using `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: I wouldn't say that is the best way to pass multiple parameters in though. @Squirrel is right there.

Comment: true, a table valued parameter could work better. as always, it's up to how the OP chooses to resolve.